# Generic function in html with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use a generic type method (`myFunction<type>(args)`) in an html file between double curly brackets.

However since the `< >` characters are interpreted as html I am getting a **Template parse error**

```
<button class="flag-button" *ngFor="let country of countries" mat-menu-item (click)="selectCountry(c)">
  <mat-icon>language</mat-icon>
  <span>{{country.get<string>('name')}}</span>
</button>
```

I know that there are many cleaner ways out of this problem, but just out of curiosity, do you know any way to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) or casting in an Angular html template?

Comment: Types aren't part of the Angular template syntax: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax. Have you actually had an issue calling `country.get('name')` from the template?

Comment: Nope, it's working fine.
But it won't be type safe right ?

Comment: What would it actually mean to be type safe at that point? The types won't exist at runtime anyway and you can interpolate any kind of value into that span. If you want to do type-safe *operations*, note anything non-trivial probably shouldn't be done in the template anyway.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right!

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe said in the comments, types aren't checked in Angular templates.
They will not exist at runtime as the code is compiled to Javascript anyway.

Typing should not be handled in the HTML and as I said in my question there are better ways to do this (calling a method in the .ts file is one of them)